# pm2 start app command working but it gives error in status

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, yarnpkg, pm2

for background process running i am using `pm2` npm, when i try to run this command

```
pm2 start yarn --interpreter bash --name test -- start
```

in status it gives me errored when i checked with `pm2 list` command, here i have given that list, manually `yarn start` command works for me, here whole oputput for me

```
[PM2] Starting /usr/local/bin/yarn in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name        │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ test---     │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 24567    │ 0      │ 1    │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ root     │ disabled │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
[PM2][WARN] Current process list running is not in sync with saved list. Type 'pm2 save' to synchronize or enable autosync via 'pm2 set pm2:autodump true'
```

can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Try `pm2 logs 0` to view logs then know what's the issue.

Comment: it gives me error : /usr/local/bin/yarn: line 7: var: command not found

Comment: please give me the result of `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have Yarn installed using npm, in which case `/usr/local/bin/yarn` will link to the node script `yarn.js` (as defined in its `package.json`) and not the bash script `yarn`. So `bash yarn start` (what you are essentially doing) won't work.

Try this instead, without interpreter:

```
pm2 start yarn --name test -- start
```